How do I sort an alphanumeric column using a custom alphabetical order?
I want to arrange by a column alphabetically, but customize the alphabetical order. I need to treat digits as coming after letters.
For example, if this is my input,
data.frame(x = c("a1", "a1a", "0a", "za", "2a", "a2", "0ab", "0aa"))

I need the output to look like this:
data.frame(x = c("a1", "a1a", "a2", "za", "0a", "0aa", "0ab", "2a"))

What practical methods exist for accomplishing this in R?
Base R, Tidyverse, and Data.Table solutions are all welcome.

you could create a helper column defining if the first character is a letter or a digit. Then you could sort by a) this helper columm followed by b) the actual string.

This is a base R solution.  I'll assume you're working in a locale where letters sort in English alphabetical order, and digits sort ahead of them.  So the idea is to translate characters and sort on the translated strings.
# This is standard collation order
standard <- "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

# This is the special order that should be used in our string
special  <- "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789"

df <- data.frame(x = c("a1", "a1a", "0a", "za", "2a", "a2", "0ab", "0aa"))

# First, modify the "special" chars in our string to their standard
# equivalent
modified <- chartr(old = special, new = standard, tolower(df$x))

# Now sort the dataframe using the modified strings
df[order(modified),]

I used tolower(df$x) because standard sorting (not computer sorting as done by sort()) doesn't distinguish by case.  If your real data has mixed case letters, and you care about how things like c("a", "A") get sorted, then you'd use different standard and special vectors, and wouldn't use tolower().

An inferior, but entertaining solution:
library(tidyverse)

DF <- data.frame(x = c("a1", "a1a", "0a", "za", "2a", "a2", "0ab", "0aa"))

DF %>% 
  mutate(new_x = x %>% 
           str_replace_all("0", "═") %>% 
           str_replace_all("1", "╔") %>% 
           str_replace_all("2", "╚") %>% 
           str_replace_all("3", "╠") %>% 
           str_replace_all("4", "╤") %>% 
           str_replace_all("5", "╦") %>% 
           str_replace_all("6", "╧") %>% 
           str_replace_all("7", "╨") %>% 
           str_replace_all("8", "╩") %>% 
           str_replace_all("9", "╬")) %>% 
  arrange(new_x) %>% 
  select(-new_x)


Instead of replacing your original column back and forth, rather create a new column, sort by it and delete it afterwards.

You could do (I‘m keeping the extra columns for illustrative purposes):
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(x = c("a1", "a1a", "0a", "za", "2a", "a2", "0ab", "0aa")) %>%
  mutate(helper = str_sub(x, 1, 1),
         digit = if_else(str_detect(helper, '[0-9]'), 1, 0)) %>%
  arrange(digit, x)

which gives:
    x helper digit
1  a1      a     0
2 a1a      a     0
3  a2      a     0
4  za      z     0
5  0a      0     1
6 0aa      0     1
7 0ab      0     1
8  2a      2     1


This doesn't work for the entire string.
